# A navigation menu like http://vimeo.com/

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering how i might build a similar navigation through css and eventually js. I have no problem replicating the "static" part, what i would like to know is how to make the drop down menu as they made it.

Like the whole page slides to make space for it, it does not overlap like in all the scripts i found.Id appreciate an explanation or even better a ready made script somewhere on the web that i haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/itekuv/8/edit)*

jQuery:

```
$('nav li:has(ul)').on('hover',function(){
    $('ul', this).stop().animate({height:'toggle'},300); 
});
```

HTML

```
  <nav>    
    <ul>      
      <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>      
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>      
      <li>
          <a href="#">Watch</a>
          <ul>
              <h2>Watch additional menu</h2>      
          </ul>     
      </li>            
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* ALL ULs */
nav ul{
  list-style:none;
  width:100%;
}

/* INNER UL */
nav li > ul{
  float:left;
  display:none;
  background:#ccc;
}

/* ALL LI */
nav li{
  display:inline;
  margin:30px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. After a lot of tinkering i got it to work, just one more thing, how do i get it to "stay out" while moused over? What i mean is that if i try and hover "watch additional menu" it will slide back in.

Comment: @ChristopherGibbs edited my answer and simplified the code

Comment: Im sorry for being such a pain in the ass, youve been awesome, but is there any way to obtain the same effect with the first version of the script you posted? Its not that im being lazy, its just that i think it suits better my needs as i can have different drop down layouts for each tab, but with this simplified version (wich is still awesome and i appreciate the effort) i dont think i can. I really owe you a beer.

Comment: this was the previous code snippet, in case you didnt have it anymore:
    $('nav li').on('mouseenter mouseleave hover',function( e ){ $('#'+$(this).data('open'))[e.type=='mouseenter'?'slideDown':'slideUp'](); });